# Multiple Channel Snippets Youtube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm looking to lookup multiple channel details at once something like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={KEY}&part=snippet&channelId={Channel1ID},{Channel2ID}
```

But i can't find the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to lookup for multiple channels details at once (and not videos or playlists) then [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) is the way to go.

More technically [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={KEY}&part=snippet&id={Channel1ID},{Channel2ID}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=%7BKEY%7D&part=snippet&id=%7BChannel1ID%7D,%7BChannel2ID%7D) is exactly what you need.